# How can covert my sjPlot table "sjt.df" in LaTeX table

Tags: r

I'm trying the following code, I have an output: pdf_document

````
```{r}
# load package
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
# load sample data set.
data(efc)
```
```{r}
library(lazyWeave)
options(lazyReportFormat = "latex")
```
````

Option 1

````
```{r, results='asis'}
lazy.matrix(sjt.df(efc, no.output=TRUE)$knitr)
```
````

Option 2

````
 ```{r, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(sjt.df(efc, no.output=TRUE)$knitr, format = "rst")
```
````

My goal is to print the table when I use pdf format

Comment: sjt.df creates an HTML table, why are you using it if you want to print out a PDF?

Comment: Because SjPlot throws me the N, raw%, valid% and cumulative%, which does not make it xtable or pander. My question is if there is way to use sjPlot with pdf outputs

Comment: I would say it's not going to happen, I'm not familiar with the sj tools, but it looks as if they spit out HTML. You might look at some alternatives like those described here http://www.statmethods.net/stats/descriptives.html .

Comment: Workaround: Copy the HTML table to Excel and then use the Excel Maro "excel2latex"